# Laravel where through each collection item

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following query which retruns a list of up to 10 items:

```
$type1Counters = TypeEffects::where('defence',$defender->type1_id)
        ->where("modifier",'>',1)
        ->get();
```

This query return a collection of TypeEffects. Each typeeffects has `type_id` column in it.

I have Defender object in my database, which has `type1_id` and `type2_id` columns.

**Main goal**

I need to get all defenders, **WHERE** their `type1_id` or `type2_id` columns equal to each collection item type_id I got in my `$type1Counters` query. I've been thinking about looping through my `$type1Counters`, but then I end up with something like this:

```
foreach ($type as $type1Counters) {
$x++;
$defender[$x] = Defender::where('type1_id',$type->type_id)
->orWhere('type2_id',$type->type_id);
}
```

but then I end up with an array of collections while I need all of them in one collection, order by defender `power` column.

Any ideas how I can get one collection for all of the defenders with the types I Found in my `$type1Counters` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `whereIn`, which will look for all the items in the array you pass it.

```
$type1Counters = TypeEffects::where('defence',$defender->type1_id)
        ->where("modifier",'>',1)
        ->groupBy('type_id')
        ->pluck('type_id');
```

`$type1Counters` will be an array with all the possibles `type_ids`. 
Now you can fetch all the Defenders of said types:

```
Defender::whereIn('type1_id', $type1Counters)
    ->orWhereIn('type2_id',$type1Counters)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you! Assuming I have an array of types in the $type1Countesr array, and in the end of all I want to return all those types in that array with all the data in it( All the TypeEffects, not only the ID plucking). How I can do that without making another same query without the pluck?